# Why do we use the same parameters for the joint, marginal and conditional distributions in VAEs?

Tags: machine-learning, autoencoders, variational-bayes, generative-models, variational-inference

I've noticed in several resources on variational autoencoders (for example the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_autoencoder)), we use the same parameters theta ($\theta$) for the prior, likelihood, posterior, etc distributions. For example the equation $p_\theta(x) = \int_z p_\theta(x|z)p_\theta(z)dz$. Aren't $p_\theta(x)$ and $p_\theta(z)$ two different distributions, so how can we parameterize them with the same $θ$ params. I might be misunderstanding something about what it means to parameterize a distribution with neural nets..

Answer (score 2):

Of course, it is not the same parameters that are used to parametrize the likelihood or the posterior for example, but we keep the same letter (here $\theta$) to refer to the parameters of the true (original) distributions. On the other hand, in VAEs, $\phi$ is often used to refer to the parameters to the variational distributions. Indeedn, this can sometimes be unclear.

To address your second point, let us say $p_{\theta}(x|z)$ is a Gaussian distribution, classically it is parametrized by a scalar mean $m$ and scalar a variance $s^2$ : $p_{\theta}(x|z)=\mathcal{N}(x;m,s^2)$, here $\theta=\{m,s^2\}$. Now when we say that this distribution is parametrized by a neural network we mean that $m$ and $s^2$ will be the outputs of a neural network with input $z$. Let us denote this neural network $f_{\theta}$, $\theta$ is here the set of weights and biases of the neural network. We can write $p_{\theta}(x|z)=\mathcal{N}(x;f_{\theta}(z))$.